# StreamReader.Peek for Multiline Textbox

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I coded the StreamReader.Peek method like this

```
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Textbox1.Text)
Dim line As String = ""
Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
....
```

But it came up with an exception that it could not find the file "text in textbox"
I realized the Peek method is only for text files, so is there any equivalent?
By the way Textbox1 is a Multiline textbox

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  The constructor for StreamReader that takes a string is to specify a filename to open and read.  Does Textbox1.Text contain a filename?  Or do you need to read through the data in the textbox, in which case the StringReader would be appropriate as yu_ominae stated below.  What exception do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `StringReader`? The syntax is just the same otherwise.